# Run firefox within a Linux chroot jail in FreeBSD 13.1

Tags: freebsd, chroot, jails

I have managed to install a Ubuntu chroot jail within FreeBSD 13.1. However, I need to run Firefox from it to launch Jupyter Lab from a python virtual environment within the chroot subsystem. I was wondering if I could use the FreeBSD Firefox from the subsystem. Nevertheless, I installed Firefox on the chroot subsystem and when tried to run it I gen an error as below.

```
(newEnv) schroter1@SCHROTER:~$ firefox No protocol specified Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: unix:0.0 
Error: cannot open display: unix:0.0
```

Would anyone be able to help me in this regards.

Thanks & Best Regards

Schroter Michael

Answer (score 1):

Change your DISPLAY value to be ip:0.0 where ip is the ip address of the FreeBSD system running the X server.

The use of unix:0.0 is local to the jail and it’s not a good idea to run the X server in the jail.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Would be able to know how to get the ip address of the FreeBSD system running the X server please? Thanks & Best Regards Schroter Michael

Comment: Logged into the host, not the jail, running “ifconfig -a” will show you it. Ignore 127.X.X.X

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Please refer the following for your kind perusal. Please find the below output for your kind perusal. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JQKE-DOCwZJlq1xZ1AZ1NYbZpf7ECBF1/view?usp=sharing Thanks & Best Regards Schroter MIchael

Comment: export DISPLAY=192.168.0.255:0.0

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the reply. However, I seem to get the same error. After typing `firefox` in `Ubuntu terminal` I get: `Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: 192.168.0.255:0.0
Error: cannot open display: 192.168.0.255:0.0
Thanks & Best Regards Schroter Michael`

Comment: So, to clarify. 192.168.0.255 has a netmask that is **not** 255.255.255.0? If so that ip address is the broadcast address.

Comment: Here is my FreeBSD:  `inet 192.168.1.30 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255` So you need the **192.168.1.30** not the **192.168.1.255**.

Comment: Hi, Again thanks for the reply. I stiil get `schroter1@SCHROTER:~$ firefox
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: ip:192.168.0.22:0.0
Error: cannot open display: ip:192.168.0.22:0.0
`  Please find the following link please :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bk7BTXeZwtJdzA3UijzFjB6byP61tyFp/view?usp=sharing Thanks & Best Regards Schroter Michael